# Running JUnit 3 tests with JUnit Vintage engine

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5, junit3

In our project we have quite a few JUnit 3 tests looking like:

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class JUnit3Test extends TestCase {

    public static TestSuite suite()
    {
        var suite = new TestSuite("JUnit 3 style test suite");
        suite.addTest(new JUnit3Test("JUnit 3 style test") {
            @Override
            protected void runTest() {
                testSomething();
            }
        });
        return suite;
    }

    public void testSomething() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Currently, we're executing them using JUnit 4, but I'm trying to move to JUnit 5. When I change to `useJUnitPlatform()` in the Gradle build file these tests are no longer executed.

There's a full working example in https://github.com/ulrikls/junit-vintage-alltests

Any of these changes will successfully execute the JUnit 3 test:

- Switching to JUnit 4 - `useJUnit()` instead of `useJUnitPlatform()`.
- Changing the name of the test from `JUnit 3 style test` to `testSomeLibraryMethodReturnsTrue`.
- Removing the `@RunWith(AllTests.class)` annotation and the `suite()` method.

I don't know if this example is even supposed to work in JUnit 5, there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on running JUnit 3 tests with JUnit 5. But migrating all our JUnit 3 tests is also not trivial, as the tests do various stuff in the `suite()` method.

Comment: Do you have the right dependencies? [`JUnit Vintage provides a TestEngine for running JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 based tests on the platform. It requires JUnit 4.12 or later to be present on the class path or module path.`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5)

Comment: I believe so, see https://github.com/ulrikls/junit-vintage-alltests/blob/main/lib/build.gradle

Comment: It seems that you should [configure multiple test tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493166/how-to-run-junit-5-and-junit-4-test-suites-in-gradle) for each junit version. I have tested your example with a maven project (as I don't use gradle), and it was working just fine

Comment: That's of course an option, but I'm curious why the JUnit 3 test isn't being run when the junit-vintage-engine claims to be able to do just that.

Comment: I found [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#executing_legacy_tests_with_junit_vintage) example, which they claim would work for JUnit3/4 tests as well as JUnit 5. Try with these dependencies instead of yours

Comment: I've tried changing the dependencies to the set suggested in the Gradle docs that you referred to, and it does no difference.